# html: Best way to create table of contents from h1 & h2 elements?

Tags: html, css

I have an html files with h1 and h2 elements.

What is the best way and how to create a Table of Contents in this file using these elements?

Any way to automate the process or I have to settle for creating the TOC manually?

Thanks.

Comment: You could do it client-side, with [tag:javascript], or server-side, with pretty much any server-side language. Either way, the logic is the same, unless you start getting fancy with ToC generating utils.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this on the server side using any language of your choice, and then cache the results and display them every time. Don't bother doing this in javascript because it will be work that needs to be repeated everytime.

The better approach might even be to parse the file, put in a database and the just display the TOC with an easy `SELECT` statement.